# Product by entry of positive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $2$ n-by-n positive matrices $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j\in[n]}$ and $B=(b_{ij})_{i,j\in[n]}$, could we prove their product by term $C=(a_{ij}\cdot b_{ij})_{i,j\in[n]}$ is also positive?

I saw the conclusion used directly in my linear algebra book (for undergraduate students), but I haven't got a proof. The symmetry is obvious, but for the positiveness, I can't think of any tools dealing with product "by term", and it becomes worse when I expand all its terms. Would someone give me a hint...

Comment: By positive, do you mean positive definite?

Comment: @5xum I suppose positive definite implies $\langle x,f(x) \rangle >0, \forall x\not=0$, I would like $\langle x, f(x)\rangle\ge 0, \forall x$ :)

Comment: [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem).

Comment: @pqros In future, use `\langle x,y rangle` to write $\langle x,y\rangle$ instead of `<x,y>` becasuse that produces a much uglier $<x,y>$.

Comment: @5xum Thanks, I've changed it and it looks much better now.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, I'll read the proof on Wiki.

Comment: The proofs over there are horrible. If you know about Kronecker product, the simplest (one-line) proof is to note that the Hadamard product $A\circ B$ is just a principal submatrix of the Kronecker product $A\otimes B$.

Comment: @user1551 I think the "proof using eigendecomposition" is fine, and definitely uses facts that would be covered in an undergraduate course

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$A$ is positive semidefinite iff there exists $v_i$ a set of vectors in an Euclidean space $V$ so that $a_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$. Now observe that
$$a_{ij} \cdot b_{ij} = \langle v_i \otimes w_i, v_j\otimes w_j\rangle $$ where $v_i \otimes w_i $ are vectors in $V\otimes W$.